# How to upgrade Homebrew itself (not softwares/formulas installed by it) on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, upgrade, open-source

I have homebrew installed long before the OS is upgraded a few times to 10.12.3. Now that

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 0.9.9 (git revision 080c; last commit 2016-08-11)
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision b163b; last commit 2016-08-10)
```

How to properly upgrade to newer version, say [1.1](https://brew.sh/blog/)?

```
$ brew upgrade
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The right way to solve this is to enter:

```
$ cd "$(brew --repo)" && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master && brew update
```

Found at http://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-upgrade-brew-stuck-on-0-9-9/33.

Answer (score 77):

To **update** homebrew itself, use:

```
brew update
```

To **upgrade** all packages installed using homebrew, then you have to use `brew upgrade`. You can check this [FAQ](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-update-my-local-packages) from brew website for more details.

Answer (score 13):

As a habit, I run this command once a week:

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup
```

It updates `brew` itself, casks and related packages then clears old package's unneeded files. Here is the result after running twice:

```
Already up-to-date
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to update Homebrew, use ***brew update***. After running brew update, you may have outdated formulae installed, which is where ***brew upgrade*** is necessary.

***$ git -C*** 
Takes an existing commit object, and reuses the log messages and the authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating a commit.

***/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core*** 
This is the path to the homebrew-core folder on a computer.

***fetch*** 
Downloads objects and references from another repository.

***--unshallow*** 
This is a git fetch option. If the source repository is complete, it converts a shallow repository to a complete one, removing all the limitations imposed by shallow repositories.

***brew update*** 
Updates the Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands

```
$ git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow  
$ brew update
```

Comment: I think some explanation of what these commands do would be useful.